# get a row from a table and having it at first position of a query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I would like to know if exist a way to get a row from a table through MySQL and having it at the first position of a result query. For example

this is the table

```
1 Item_1
2 Item_2
3 Item_3
4 Item_4
```

I would like to get as result when for instance I ask for Item_3 a result like this:

```
3 Item_3
1 Item_1
2 Item_2
4 Item_4
```

is it possible

Comment: ORDER BY col = 'item_3' DESC,col - or see FIELD()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
order by case when column_2 = 'Item_3' 
              then 1 
              else 2 
         end asc, 
         other_column_Order asc
```

or especially for MySQL

```
select * from your_table
order by column_2 <> 'Item_3', 
         other_column_Order asc
```